# How to validate an existing xml file against an existing .xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to validate and existing .xml file against an existing .xsd file. As is, both files are in my **bin** folder. However my method is only having trouble finding my .xsd file. It finds the .xml file then validates it against nothing because it obviously cannot find the .xsd file. I think this may be for one of two reasons,

1. I shouldn't have the .xsd file in the **bin** file or
2. I am not adding the .xsd file correctly with `settings.Schemas.Add("VM", "v.config.xsd");` because I am not quite sure what the first string parameter "VM" does. I used the parameter defined as name="VM" within my v.config.xsd for this parameter.

It might not be because of either of these 2 reasons (this is my first time doing this) so any pointers are welcome. Here is my method:

```
public void Validate()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add("VM", "v.config.xsd");
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("output.xml", settings);

            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(reader);
            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);

            document.Validate(eventHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    private static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + args.Message);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);
    }
```

The error message returned is:

```
 Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred.Could not find schema information for the element 'element1'
 Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred.Could not find schema information for the element 'element2'
```

And it outputs this message for every element in the "output" file.

Answer (score 0):

Your application actually find the xsd file inside your bin folder but, as decribed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.add(v=vs.110).aspx), the methods signature

```
Settings.Schemas.Add("schema", "v.config.xsd");
```

try to validate your XML against the schema called *schema*

If your schema name into xml is *urn:pippo*, try to use

```
Settings.Schemas.Add("urn:pippo", "v.config.xsd");
```

Comment: So this is the name within the schema? So where it says "name=VM". So in my case the name is VM. I changed my code accordingly and I still get the same error.

Comment: Please, add a piace of consistent XML and take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.schemas(v=vs.110).aspx for more example.

Comment: What do you mean by consistent xml?

Comment: Hei Guy! If you wanna get help here please post your damn XML so we can help you. Is not too muche diffucult. Posto your XML. Thank you